# How react to message send to parent window in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

for training purpose I build my own class derived from `CWnd` called `CMyClass`. In this class I built my own Listcontrol where the user can insert items which show then as lines in a child window. But now I wanted to have a change in the mouse icon, whenever the mouse hovers over such a line in the child window, the problem is, I overwrited the `OnSetCursor` function, but within the parent class, however, my parent class doesn't know how many lines are in my child window and where they are located. Right now, I was able to change the mouse icon, when the mouse hovers over the entire child window:

```
BOOL CMyCustomListCtrlDlg::OnSetCursor(CWnd* pWnd, UINT nHitTest, UINT message)
{
    CRect rect;
    Variable1.GetWindowRect(&rect);
    ScreenToClient(rect);
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    ScreenToClient(&p);
    CPoint punkt = p;

    if (rect.PtInRect(punkt))
    {
        ::SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_HAND));
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        ::SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW));
        return TRUE;
    }
    return CDialogEx::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
}
```

Variable1 is the variable of my self build child class. Is there a way to react to the `OnSetCursor` funtion from inside the child class? Or in other words, how can I tell the parent window, where the 'interesting' points are and how to react to them?

tried to overwrite the `OnChildNotify` function.

Comment: Since you are already subclassing the control (ie you do define and instantiate a custom class), wouldn't it be simple enough to a define a member function? It should be taking the cursor coordinates as parameters and return the cursor type or some "state". It should be called from your `OnSetCursor()` handler. That is, the parent dlg will be asking the control "For these cursor coordinates, which cursor should be displayed?".